# OpenZeppelin ERC721 URIStorage implementation missing enumerable functions

Tags: erc-721, openzeppelin

I'm trying to build an ERC721 contract using the default OpenZeppelin 4.x ERC721URIStorage implementation. In the documentation at this URL (https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/erc721) you can find the following text:

*The ERC721URIStorage contract is an implementation of ERC721 that includes all standard extensions (IERC721Metadata and IERC721Enumerable).*

Now, if you check the IERC721Enumerable interface documentation here (https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/token/erc721#IERC721Enumerable) you can see that there is a **tokenOfOwnerByIndex** function but unfortunately it is not available at the OpenZeppelin ERC712URIStorage implementation as it was supposed to according to documentation.

Am I missing something or is OpenZeppelin documentation wrong?

Here is the code:

```
// contracts/GameItem.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract GameItem is ERC721URIStorage {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

    constructor() ERC721("GameItem", "ITM") {}

    function awardItem(address player, string memory tokenURI)
        public
        returns (uint256)
    {
        _tokenIds.increment();

        uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
        _mint(player, newItemId);
        _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);

        return newItemId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> The ERC721URIStorage contract is an implementation of ERC721 that
> includes all standard extensions (IERC721Metadata and
> IERC721Enumerable).

**nope**, the ERC721 oz implementation only includes the `IERC721Metadata` extension and not the `IERC721Enumerable`

the `tokenOfOwner` is available as part of `ERC721Enumerable` extension

And you're only inheriting from `ERC721URIStorage`, which intern only inherits from the `ERC721` implementation, which only includes the `Metadata extension`

see underneath the description for the ERC721 implementation which is used by `ERC721URIStorage` and your example contract:

> Implementation of ERC721 Non-Fungible Token Standard, including the Metadata extension, but not including the Enumerable extension, which is available separately as ERC721Enumerable.

---

A complete implementation for your example would be as follows:

```
// contracts/GameItem.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract GameItem is ERC721URIStorage, ERC721Enumerable, Ownable {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

    constructor() ERC721("GameItem", "ITM") {}

    function awardItem(address player, string memory tokenURI)
        public
        returns (uint256)
    {
        _tokenIds.increment();

        uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
        _mint(player, newItemId);
        _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);

        return newItemId;
    }
    
    function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId)
        internal
        override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)
    {
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);
    }

    function _burn(uint256 tokenId) internal override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage) {
        super._burn(tokenId);
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage)
        returns (string memory)
    {
        return super.tokenURI(tokenId);
    }

    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)
        returns (bool)
    {
        return super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
    }

    function safeMint(address to, uint256 tokenId) public onlyOwner {
        _safeMint(to, tokenId);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the _burn and tokenURI function, checkout the wizard here and add URI storage as one of your features: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/wizard

Answer (score 0):

IDK how I feel about my answer, but what I did is i went into my node_modules folder, and copied all the code from ERC721Enumerable into ERC721URIStorage and that's how I was able to combine both modules. Not sure if this is a correct workaround but it's managed to work in my code so far

Comment: Although this works, Its bad practice to modify Open Zeppelin's contracts